# In Django, using a generic list class, how can I get N of an object_list from the same field type

Tags: django, django-views

I have a like model that collects likes that users select on books.

So, each record has the user_id, like_id and book_id.

I want a url that is something like:

```
(?P<top_num>\d+)/likes/
```

Wich would be directed to a view that does something like this:

```
class TopLikes(ListView):
    """ Get all the archived projects """

    queryset = Like.objects.filter(display=True)
    template_name = "books/TopLikes.html"
    paginate_by = 10

    @method_decorator(login_required)
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(TopLikes, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
```

What I don't know is how to take that `top_num` as the number to pass to the view to return the top ten books with the most likes.

it would make sense to me to do something like `queryset = Like.objects.filter(display=True).annotate(num_books=Count('books')).order_by('num_books')`

It makes sense to me to get the likes and then use the likes to do something like this in the template:

```
{% for object in object_list  %}
    {{ object.book.title }} with {{ object|length }}
{% endfor %}
```

Would this just be easier to do as a custom view?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

1. **Override get_queryset() method**, so that you can add custom filtering
2. **Use self.kwargs**, so that you can use top_num url parameter to limit your queryset
3. **Use {{ object.num_books }}**, because well what is {{ object|length }} supposed to do anyway :)

Example:

```
class TopLikes(ListView):
    """ Get all the archived projects """

    queryset = Like.objects.filter(display=True)
    template_name = "books/TopLikes.html"
    paginate_by = 10

    def get_queryset(self):
        qs = super(TopLikes, self).get_queryset()
        qs = qs.annotate(num_books=Count('books')).order_by('num_books')
        qs = qs[:self.kwargs['top_num']]
        return qs
```

Comment: so, it's working but num_books only returns one record, not the count of all the books. I think I need to create an additional variable that has just the count. something like `qs = qs.annontate(total_num_books=Count('books')` is that accurate?

Comment: I had to un-answer it. It's actually not working. At least as well as I've described what I need to have happen. It looks like it should be returning a list of likes, with the ones that have the most books first. But changing the ascension or descension doesn't change the return order. Any ideas?

Comment: sure, all you have to do is post the minimal code necessary to reproduce your problem: stripped models with minimal data exported as json, striped urls, striped template. TYIA :)

Comment: yeah, it would help if I supplied all the information ;-). I'll repost later today.